Removing extrapolation between telluric gap removal in spectra
Here is the problem.
Im plotting a spectra of data and attempting to remove telluric lines in sections of the spectra, however python is extrapolating between the removed sections, and I cant think of a way to remove them. The difficulties in resolving it myself lie in my skill set.
I have tried the following code and tried several variations



import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

# Loads a single spectrum file to test
spectrum_file = '/Users/xxxx/Desktop/Telluric/aligned_spectrum_.2015-12-04T09-46-42.800.txt'
data = np.loadtxt(spectrum_file)  #loads the data from the text file
wavelengths, intensity = data[:, 0], data[:, 1]  #Extracts the first and second columns of the data into wavelengths and intensity arrays.


# Telluric regions in nanometers - list of tuples  to define the start and the end
telluric_regions_nm = [
    (502.0, 510.0),
    (568.0, 580.0),
    (586.5, 601.0),
    (627.0, 633.5),
    (644.5, 661.0),
    (686.0, 700.0)
]

def mask_telluric_regions(wavelengths, telluric_regions):
    mask = np.ones_like(wavelengths, dtype=bool)  #initialises a mask array with 'True' values of the same shape as 'wavelengths'
    for region in telluric_regions:
        start, end = region
        region_mask = (wavelengths >= start) & (wavelengths <= end)
        mask &= ~region_mask   #updates the mask to set 'False for wavelengths within the telluric regions'
    return mask 

# Create a mask for the telluric regions
mask = mask_telluric_regions(wavelengths, telluric_regions_nm) #calls the def mask function 

# Plot the original spectrum
plt.figure(figsize=(14, 6))
plt.plot(wavelengths, intensity, label='Original Spectrum', alpha=0.5)

# Plot only the cleaned segments without connecting the gaps
cleaned_spectrum = np.full_like(intensity, np.nan)
cleaned_spectrum[mask] = intensity[mask]

plt.plot(wavelengths, cleaned_spectrum, label='Cleaned Spectrum', color='blue')

plt.xlabel('Wavelength (nm)')
plt.ylabel('Intensity')
plt.title('Masked Spectrum')
plt.show()

